# Proof that two sets are equal

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

$X$ is finite, if and only if, the affirmation is true,

$$Y\subseteq X \text{ and } f:Y\to X\text{ surjective } \Rightarrow Y=X$$

It is easy to see that this result is true, but I am not able to properly the solution, mainly the direction $(\Leftarrow)$. What I managed to write for the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ is the following,

We have that: $X$ is finite and $Y \subseteq X \text{ and } f:Y \to X \text{ surjective}$. Let's prove that $X=Y$.

Note that: if $X \neq Y$, then there is some element $x \in X$ such that $ x \notin Y$. By hypothesis, $Y$ is a subset of $X$, that is finite, so we have that $Y$ is finite and yet $|Y| \leq |X|$. Thus, there are bijections $\phi_{n}:I_n \to X$ and $\psi_{m}:I_m \to Y $, where $ m \leq n $. But, since $f:Y \to X$ is surjective, that is, $\forall x \in X, \exists \, y \in Y$ such that $ f(y)=x$, and also $|Y|\leq |X|$, there cannot be $x\in X $ such that $x\notin Y$. Thus, we conclude that $X =Y$.

Is this solution correct? Could someone help me in the other direction?

**Edit:**

A set $A$ is said to be finite, if it is empty or if there is a bijection $\varphi: I_n \to A$, where $A=\{1,\cdots,n\}$.

Comment: What notion of finiteness are you using?

Comment: @DonThousand $X$ is finite if exist a bijection $g:I_n \to X$ where $I_n=\{1,\cdots ,n\}$.

Comment: Your solution is not correct.  It's not true that $X \neq Y$ implies that for some $x, x \in X$ and $x \notin Y$.  It's possible that $X \subset Y$.

Comment: I cannot follow the argument in your last two sentences (starting with "However..."). Note that you must use finiteness of $X$ in an essential way, as the statement is false for infinite $X$. What do you do with $\phi_n$ and $\psi_m$?

Comment: If $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$, then there's no $x \in X$ such that $x \notin Y$, but nevertheless $X \neq Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⇒

Suppose X finite, $ Y \subset X $ then $ |Y| \leq | X |$, $ f: Y \to X $ surjective then $ |X| \leq |Y |$. We deduce that $ |X| = |Y| $. This together with $ X $
finite and $ Y \subset Y $ implies $ X = Y $.

⇐

Suppose by contradiction that $ X $ is infinite. We show that the implication is false. There exists $ g: \mathbb{Z} \to X $ injective. Denote by $ \bar{X} = X \setminus g(\mathbb{Z}) $. Define $ Y = X \setminus g(2\mathbb{Z}+1)$, and $ f : Y \to X $ such that $ f(x) = x $ for $ x \in \bar{X} $ and $ f(x) = g\left(\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)$ for $ x \in g(2 \mathbb{Z})$.  It is straight-forward to show that $ f $ is surjective but $ X \neq Y $ which implies that the implication is false.